# How to remove a certain number from a comma delimited list of numbers

Tags: php

I have this comma delimited list `0,0,0,0,5,0,7,8,9,10` and i would like to get rid of the number zero represented as a number on its own right and not the zero in `10`.

The list is represented in the variable `$str` and this is the code i am trying to remove the zero with.

```
$str;

$myArray = explode(',', $str);

if (($key = array_search('0', $myArray)) !== false) {
    unset($myArray[$key]);
}
print_r($myArray);
$csv = implode(', ', $myArray);
echo $csv;
```

but this gives `0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10`

This code does not do the job as i would have liked.What can i do to get rid of the zeros?.

Comment: to get a right output you should reindex the array after `unset`: `if (($key = array_search('0', $myArray)) !== false) {
    unset($myArray[$key]);
} 
$myArray = array_values($myArray);
print_r($myArray);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) comes to the rescue:

```
$myArray = explode(',', '0,0,0,0,5,0,7,8,9,10');
print_r(array_filter($myArray, function($el) { return $el; }));
// ⇒ 
/*
Array
(
    [4] => 5
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
*/
```

Comment: Actually, you don't have to pass a callback, because if no callback is supplied all entries equal to `false` will be removed.

Comment: I know; I just wanted to provide more generic solution (e.g. OP wants to remove “1”s or like.)

Answer (score -1):

Use `str_replace` function - works great and it is not much different than you code so you wont make changes just you must add str_replace function:

```
$myArray = explode(',', str_replace(array(' 0,',',0'), '',$str) );

if (($key = array_search('0', $myArray)) !== false) {
   unset($myArray[$key]);
}
print_r($myArray);
$csv = implode(', ', $myArray);
echo $csv;
```

Comment: `str_replace('0,', '',$str)` will leave the trailing zero intact.

Comment: I mean your code **fails** on `'0,5,0,7,8,9,10,5,0'` and eats zeroes from `10`, `20` etc.

Comment: Wrong again. Would you mind **to test** you “solution” before pasting it? `'0,5,0,7,8,9,10,5,0' ⇒ '5,7,8,9,15'`